# How to import modules from site-packages when in a different directory?

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x

I made a module and moved it to `/root/Downloads/Python-3.5.2/Lib/site-packages`.

When I run bash command `python3` in this folder to start the ide and import the module it works. However if I run `python3` in any other directory (e.g. `/root/Documents/Python`) it says

```
ImportError: No module named 'exampleModule'
```

I was under the impression that Python would automatically search for modules in `site-packages` regardless of the directory. How can I fix it so that it will work regardless of where I am?

Comment: Paths `/root/Documents/Python` and `/root/Downloads/Python-3.5.2/` are not the same.

Comment: I know they're not the same. My point is that from what I understand when you import a module in Python it will automatically search site-packages for the module, regardless of whether you're in that directory or not.

Comment: Then you're under the wrong impression. You need to add the path to your module to a `.pth` file (new or existing) that is in the `/root/Downloads/Python-3.5.2/Lib/site-packages` directory. See the [site module's documention](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site).

Comment: @J.Doe That's *a* `site-packages` directory, but it is not one that appears in your Python path (except when it is found via the current working directory).

Comment: This will give you a list of the directories searched by default, it is created when python is installed:  `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of moving the module I would suggest you add the location of the module to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  If this is set then the python interpreter will know where to look for your module.

e.g. on Linux

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<insert module location here>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is two ways to make python find your module:

1. add the path where you module reside in your `PYTHONPATH` as suggested by bmat
2. add the path where you module reside in your script like this:

   ```py
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, '/root/Downloads/Python-3.5.2/Lib/site-packages')
   ```

Comment: You mean `sys.path.insert`, not `sys.insert`.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are a window user and you are getting import issues from site-packages
then you can add the path of your site-packages to env variable**

[image]

C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages
(site-package directory)